# How are Perl Catalyst actions implemented?

Tags: perl, catalyst

How is the following code implemented in Perl?

```
sub add_item : Local {
     my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

     my $item_id = $c->req->param("item");

     push @{ $c->session->{items} }, $item_id;

  }
```

I am interested in the **add_item : Local** part, cause I don't think those are Perl keywords.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are attributes. See [the attribute](http://perldoc.perl.org/attributes.html) documentation, but also [Private Variable via my()](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my()) and [Subroutine Attributes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Subroutine-Attributes) in [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html).

Comment: Interesting! I thought those were implemented with the help of a source filter.

Comment: You know, I hear you can "read the source" to determine this.